# A black page shows instead of splash screen in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have used a **splash screen** in Android before, and it worked fine. However, now the image that I'm using is hidden and black page shows!!

I have shared my activity and XML file, any help is appreciated?

Thanks

here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textStyle="bold">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_atrin"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_splash"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and my activity class is as follows :

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
private View mContentView;
private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
};
private View mControlsView;
private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hide();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls_splash);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_splash);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {
            super.start();
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullscreenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    thread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delayedHide(100);
}

private void hide() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}



  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Why it shows a black page? any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are overriding your `Imageview` with black `overlay`, try swapping their order(`FrameLayout` top and `RelativeLayout` bottom) like below

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_splash"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textStyle="bold">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_atrin"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks , it was a bad mistake !